# Dyanmically creating an instance of a class in AS3 (not in Library)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to create an instance of a class based on the variable sent to me from the function initiation.

This class is not a displayObject and is not in the Flash library. This seems to mean that the following does not work:

```
private function BasicControl(_stage:int):void {
        var s1:tut_stage = getDefinitionByName("stage"+_stage) as tut_stage;
        trace(s1);
        s1.Begin();
    }
```

This results in:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable stage1 is not defined.
at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()
at kazo::Main/BasicControl()[B:\Users\Kevin SSD\client\temp_tutorial\preview_src\kazo\Main.as:76]
at kazo::Main/SWFLoadComplete()[B:\Users\Kevin SSD\client\temp_tutorial\preview_src\kazo\Main.as:113]
```

However, if it is written as:

```
var s1:tut_stage = new stage1;
```

This will work fine.

How does one go about dynamically calling a class if it is not in the library? It seems that all of my efforts are returning no results. The only way that I can get this to work is using a horrible work around:

```
private function BasicControl(_stage:int):void {
        var s1:tut_stage;

        switch(_stage) {
            case 1:
                s1 = new stage1;
                break;

            case 2:
                s2 = new stage2;
                break;

        }
    }
```

I must be missing something here - How should I be calling stage1 in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getDefinitionByName` function returns a class reference. Try this instead:

```
var Clazz:Class = getDefinitionByName("stage" + _stage) as Class;
var s1:tut_stage = new Clazz() as tut_stage;
```

Additionally, you have to ensure that your classes are being included in the SWF at compile-time. Just reference them somewhere to force Flash to include them.

```
stage1; stage2;
```

You'll need to add references for any classes you want to include, but you'll only have to do this once.

Comment: ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable stage1 is not defined.
 at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()

I was under the impression getDefintionByName only worked for things that are within the library, as if I create something in the library with the linkage set as 'stage1', this then works

Comment: @KevinMcGowan I'm guessing that the class is not being included when you use the `getDefinitionByName` method because it's not referenced anywhere else. What are the `stage1`, `stage2`, etc. classes? Where are they defined?

Comment: They're not referenced anywhere, I assumed I would be able to create a new instance of them without having to do so, am I wrong there? The stage1/2 classes extend tut_stage and control the tutorial for that particular stage, they are just classes and do not appear onscreen (tut_stage does not extend anything and is never placed onscreen, they just control the tutorial flow). They reference back to main through an instance. Would the solution here be to create 5 separate instances (var _s1:tut_stage = new stage1();)?

Comment: @KevinMcGowan Flash will automatically determine which classes to include in your compiled SWF based on which ones are used, so if they're not referenced anywhere, they won't be included. Try adding `import` statements somewhere to ensure their inclusion. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @KevinMcGowan Actually, on second thought, it looks like `import` in Flash does very little. Try the version I edited into my answer instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly. It does feel very strange having to do this, though, but it gave me the desired result. Just as a final question, is what I'm doing here considered correct, or would there be a better way?

Comment: @KevinMcGowan It's awkward, yes, but there's no "better" way around it. I'd definitely put a comment with it that explains why it's there, since it's a little non-obvious. Interestingly, it sort of reflects AS3's ECMAScript roots, since classes are basically still functions. You're just referencing them.